# Drools Timer based rule fires multiple times after restart

Tags: timer, drools, rule-engine, drools-fusion

I have a scenario where I want to use rules purely as a scheduled job for invoking other services. I am using a solution similar to Answer 2 on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16845777/execute-drools-rule-at-certain-time-or-fact). So I have rule 1 which looks like:

```
rule "ServiceCheck"

timer ( int: 3m 5m )

no-loop true
when
then
    boolean isServiceEnabled = DummyServices.getServiceEnabledProperty();
    if(isServiceEnabled){
        ServicesCheck servicesCheck = new ServicesCheck();      
        servicesCheck.setServiceEnabled(true);
        insert(servicesCheck);
    }
end
```

This inserts a servicesCheck object every 5 minutes if services are enabled. Once this object is inserted my other rules fire and retract the servicesCheck fact from there.

The problem I am facing is when I switch off the app and start it next day. At that time, the ServiceCheck rule gets fired a load of times before coming to a stop. My assumption is that the last fired time is saved in the session and when I restart, it finds a difference between current time and saved time and fires the rules for number of times till the 2 times match in the session. So effectively, to catch up for 1 hr gap from shutdown to restart, it will fire the rule 12 times in this case as the interval set is 5 mins. Is there a way using which I can update the last fired time on the rules session so that it starts working like a fresh new start without catching up for lost time.

Comment: BTW: I'd like to express my disagreement with questions where an adequate answer is commented with "I had thought of this too" without indicating this in the first place. Just waste my time, huh?

Comment: I had represented the issue of rule firing for a specific number of times before it started following the interval. The issue was not with the condition as the rule works absolutely fine after it syncs up with the clock. Your solution putting a condition is not solving this as well. If you feel, its a waste of your time, please skip my question, but I dont see a reason to -1 my question.

Comment: Please explain why insertion and removal of a "trigger" fact does not solve your problem. I understand that you just don't want the (small) additional overhead involved with managing this fact.

Comment: Also, the effect you're experiencing may depend on the Drools version you are using - which one is it? Also, you haven't confirmed that you persist the session, or explained how you stop and restart the "application" - or just the Knowledge/KieSession?

Comment: Thanks for the response.Yes,I persist the entire session as I use jBPM as well.Version of Drools is 5.5.0 Final.The singleton session is auto-saved automatically with jBPM API.Since I am using the timer object, I see that timer gets the next fire time stamp set on it as     setNextFireTimestamp(trigger.hasNextFireTime().getTime()).So if this time is set as 18:00 and we stopped the application (and session internally) at 17:59 and start it up at 18:11, the trigger fires 3 times for the following created schedules (1800,1805,1810).This happens even if we used a fact.

Comment: So I'Ve run an experiment - see the "Later" section in my answer. There's no telling what goes wrong in your approach, but there's no reason a timer rule *after being reliably stopped* should generate activations after the session is restarted. Did you ever attach a listener to see and verify what happens before everything is persisted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you are persisting the entire session? I suppose you have a shutdown procedure. You can use a single Fact, let's call it `Trigger`. Modify your rule to

```
rule "ServiceCheck"
  timer ( int: 3m 5m )
when
  Trigger()
then
  // ... same
end
```

You'll have to insert one Trigger fact after startup and *retract it during shutdown*.

**Later**

I've set up an experiment (using 5.5.0) where a session is running, being called with fireUntilHalt in one thread, with a rule like "ServiceCheck". Another thread will sleep some time, halt the session after retracting the Trigger fact. After more than double the interval of the timer firing, the second thread inserts the Trigger again, signals the first thread to re-enter fireUntilHalt(), and the second thread will repeat its cycle. **I can observe silence during the period where the Trigger is retracted.**

If, however, the Trigger is not retracted/re-inserted, there'll be a burst of firings after the session has been restarted.

This indicates that retracting and re-inserting a Trigger does indeed stop and restart a timer rule.

Comment: I had thought of this too, but this adds an additional requirement to keep a fact reference available throughout the application uptime to use for retracting during shutdown. Are there any best practices to use rules where "when" is blank (eval(true)) for situations like mine?

Comment: You can't evade Logic. As you say, an empty "when" part just means "true", and this implies that the timer should indeed fire every so often. If you don't want that, you'll have to create a condition that does reflect what you need. That's a dictate of Logic, and you can't evade... --- However, why use a rule if you can't/don't want to handle the consequences of using it *right*? Java will let you set up the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for the update.The approach that you provided yesterday works fine. With a fact, the jobs stop and do not create unnecessary activations.So I think I will ultimately need to use a fact to make this work.I was trying to use the first rule purely as a cron job that inserts facts that trigger the rest of the jobs, it works fine but gives issues on restart.I used AgendaEventListener also and it showed me activations for normal jobs.It did not show anything for the events that got fired on server restart.Thanks for your help.